# 7900 XT doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: boot, gpu, gpu-driver, amdgpu, 22.10

I upgraded from a 6700 XT to a 7900 XT, and now Ubuntu won't boot. After grub, I get a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I'm able to boot into terminal mode using GRUB options, but when I try using graphics, I just get the black screen. I'm pretty new to Linux as a whole. I didn't have a chance to upgrade my graphics drivers, but I believe I had mesa drivers installed already.

Comment: Drivers are the same, nothing has to be uninstalled or installed. Drivers aren't the problem. What happens exactly? "Ubuntu won't boot" doesn't describe much. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: You know when you get that white line in the top left corner that blinks when anything is happening? Well I boot up Ubuntu, and it just goes to that. But it never actually makes it to login.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.10 uses Linux Kernel 5.19. To use an AMD 7900 GPU, you need Linux Kernel 6.0+. [1]

If you want minimal hassle and just want to use your GPU, switch to a Linux distro that supports a newer kernel. If you want Ubuntu, your best hope for the moment is to boot into terminal mode and upgrade to Linux Kernel 6.0. [2] (Note that this is officially unsupported, do at your own risk and expect failure.)

[1] https://www.phoronix.com/review/rx7900xt-rx7900xtx-linux

[2] https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/10/linux-kernel-6-0-install-ubuntu-22-04/