# AMD 7900XTX Ubuntu 22.04 not work. "The following packages have unmet dependencies"

Tags: amdgpu

I was really looking forward to my graphics card yesterday, because i didn't have any until now. after the installation into the case the trouble started. Installing the graphics driver is not fun and I just can't get it. When I tried to install the driver with amdgpu-install I got this error message:

```
Loading new amdgpu-5.18.13-1577590.22.04 DKMS files...
Building for 6.1.0-1009-oem
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.1.0-1009-oem
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.1.0-1009-oem (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.18.13-1577590.22.04/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
```

I then read on a page that before I start new installation attempts I should first delete the faulty ones. I did that, but since then I've always gotten this displayed in the console

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                             
Building dependency tree... Done
Status information is read in... Done
Try "apt --fix-broken install" to fix this.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri : Depends on (before): mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers (= 1:22.3.0.50403-1538762.22.04) but 1:22.3.0.50405-1577590.22.04 should be installed
                           Recommends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 but is not installable or
                                      But libtxc-dxtn0 is not installable
  libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends on (before): mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:22.3.0.50403-1538762.22.04) but 1:22.3.0.50405-1577590.22.04 should be installed become
                                Recommends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 but is not installable or
                                           However, libtxc-dxtn0:i386 cannot be installed
  mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers : Depends on: libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu but should not be installed
  mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 : Depends on: libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu:i386 but should not be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try "apt --fix-broken install" without specifying a package (or provide a solution).
```

One would think that if you get a graphics card for 1000$, it would run without any problems, but with such a mess, one might think that the graphics card isn't worth the money. I don't know what to do. I just want what I buy to work. Do i expect to much?
Anyone know how I get rid of these errors I have. And maybe how to install an AMD 7900XTX on Ubuntu 22.04?

I have now at least solved the problem with the unmet dependencies. I have with

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

searched for all unmet dependencies. Then I forcibly removed them all

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all "package"
```

after then

```
sudo apt autoclean
```

and then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Now i have a clean system without any unmet dependencies.
Now I still have to get the graphics card installed, but before I risk system chaos like this again, I urgently need to find out what kind of kernel I should use with Ubuntu 22.04.2 for the AMD 7900XTX

Comment: Why are you using kernel 6.1?

Comment: AMD's homepage says kernel 6+, so I've updated the kernel to 6.1
which one is better suited if not the newest one?

Comment: Newest is not always better. Did they say specifically for Ubuntu.

Comment: I got it from the link here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445765/7900-xt-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-22-10

Comment: Not what I asked.

Comment: From AMD site: AMD software and drivers are designed to work best for up-to-date operating systems. Please be sure to update your operating system before installing drivers.    that's on the Ubuntu driver from AMD

Comment: That would mean Ubuntu 23.04 the first Ubuntu to include a version 6 kernel.

Comment: I got the problem with the unmet dependencies solved. The thing with the graphics card remains. Which kernel is the right one for the AMD7900XTX in Ubuntu 22.04.2?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution was:

1. Boot from 5.19 Kernel
2. remove 6.1 Kernel
3. amdgpu-install --usecase=opencl,graphics -y

No DKMS Issues, all worked fine.